# Node JS new Date one hour mismatch

Tags: node.js

When I print this:

```
const from = new Date();
console.log(from);
```

I get this: `2017-02-13T22:55:01.395Z`
By the way it's 23:55. Why is there a one-hour mismatch?

When I do this:

```
console.log(from.getHours())
```

I get it right (`23`) which is fine. What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *string* representation of `from` printed in your question is expressed in [*UTC*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), which you can tell by the trailing `Z`.

However, `from` is also capable of expressing the point in time it represents internally in *local* time, *according to your time zone*: `from.toLocaleString()`

Similarly, `.getHours()` returns the time-of-day hour in *local* time.

The implication is that your local time is 1 hour ahead of UTC, such as in Western Europe, for instance (while DST isn't in effect).

In other words: The output you're getting is as designed.